# Compare positional parameters and write to log file

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting

I'm trying to create a bash script in Ubuntu but I need a little help. Here are my instructions.

Create a script called `matchit` that completes the following.

1. Accepts 2 positional parameters
2. IF the parameters are the same echo “Hello, %username%, we have a match!”
3. If they do not match echo “These parameters are not the same, %username%”
4. Append to a log file ~/bashlog/mylog “Script executed by %username%, Variable received where %parameter1% and %parameter2%”

The following is what I have so far. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter Name"
read user

if [ $user = vortex ]
        then echo "Hello,%username%, we have a match!"
        else echo "These parameters are not the same, %username%"
fi

>> /home/vortex/bashlog/mylog "Script executed by %username%, variable recieved where %parameter1% and %parameter2%"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below `matchit` script would do

```
#!/bin/bash
currentuser="$(whoami)"
if [ ${1:-default1} = ${2:-default2} ]
# Providing default params too to rule out empty param matches, See [1]
then
echo "Hello $currentuser, we have a match"
else
echo "Params 1 and 2 doesn't match  or empty, $currentuser"
fi
echo "Script $0 executed by $currentuser, Parameters received where ${1:-empty} and ${2:-empty}" >> ~/bashlog/mylog 
# >> for apppend
```

---

<sup>[1] -  **[GNU Shell Param Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)**</sup>

Comment: @BenjaminW. too sharp :) Thank you. Corrected.